# Interpretation of Hamiltonians writen as operators involving bras and kets

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, hamiltonian

I am reading Sakurai, and he is giving a Hamiltonian for a maser written as:

$$H=H_0+V$$

with

$$ H_0 = E_1|1\rangle\langle1|+E_2 |2\rangle\langle2|$$

and

$$V=\gamma(e^{i\omega t}|1\rangle\langle2|+e^{-i\omega t}|2\rangle\langle1|$$

It is not clear to me how to interpret this "perturbation" at first sight, before finding the solution?. In general, is there any simple interpretation of each term in an interaction that has the form $|i\rangle\langle j|$ where the $|i\rangle$'s are the eigenkets of the unperturbed $H$? I tried evolving an initial state $|i\rangle$ but I get a mess not easy to interpret.

I understand that the constants are the amplitude of a transition from one state to the other. But that doesn't tell me much, that is the consequence of each of those terms, but then, what does the term itself represent? Is it an interaction between states? What does that mean? I can interpret terms in the hamiltonian that are related to known operators, but I don't know how to interpret terms that are just transitions between states. –
How would someone come up with that hamiltonian in the first place, if you cannot interpret it in any obvious way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $ H_0 = E_1|1><1|+E_2 |2><2|$
>
> ...
>
> $V=\gamma(e^{i\omega t}|1><2|+e^{-i\omega t}|2><1|$

> It is not clear to me how to interpret this "perturbation" at first sight. In general, is there any simple interpretation of each term in an interaction that has the form |i><j| where the |i>'s are the eigenkets of the unperturbed H?

The perturbation terms are the off-diagonal elements in the full (not unperturbed) Hamiltonian. If they were not off-diagonal, then the Hamiltonian would already be diagonal and the unperturbed eigenstates would be the same as the full eigenstates.

In your case, you can write the Hamiltonian as:
$$
H = \left(
\begin{matrix}
E_1 & \gamma e^{i \omega t} \\
\gamma e^{-i\omega t} & E_2
\end{matrix}
\right)\;,
$$
where, presumably, $E_1$, $E_2$, $\gamma$, $\omega$, and $t$ are real.

---

For example, if you apply standard [time-dependent perturbation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory_(quantum_mechanics)#Time-dependent_perturbation_theory), you will find that there is a non-zero contribution to transition from state $|1\rangle$ to state $|2\rangle$ (and vice versa), given by:
$$
c_2(t) = -i\int_0^t dt' V_{21}(t')e^{-i(E_1 - E_2)t'}+O(V^2)\;,
$$
where $c_2 =\langle 2|\Psi\rangle$, and where the notation $O(V^2)$ means there are additional contributions of higher orders in the interaction strength (which are assumed to be relatively small).

In this example, we see that the terms $\omega$ and $\gamma$ will enter the calculation as:
$$
c_2(t) = -i\gamma\int_0^t dt' e^{-i(\omega + E_1 - E_2)t'}\;,
$$
where I have set $\hbar=1$. So, we see that the transition probability should be proportional (at lowest order) to $|\gamma|^2$ and that $\hbar \omega$ can be interpreted as something like the photon energy.

This latter interpretation can also be seen from Fermi's Golden Rule, which we usually arrive at by taking the lower limit to $-\infty$ and the upper limit as $\infty$ and interpreting the probability divided by the total transition time as a rate:
$$
R = 2\pi|\gamma|^2\delta(E_1+\hbar\omega - E_2)
$$

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of that, those elements are the amplitude of a transition from one state to the other. But that doesnt tell me much, that is the consequence of each of those terms, but then, what does the term itself represent? it is an interaction between states? what does that mean? I can interpret terms in the hamiltonian that are related to  known operators, but I dont know how to interpret terms that are just transitions between states.

Comment: If you want to "interpret" the parameters, you should calculate some measurable quantity of interest, like a transition rate, and see where those parameters show up.

Comment: But how would someone come up with that hamiltonian in the first place, if you cannot interpret it in any obvious way?

Comment: It is a toy hamiltonian, presumably designed for pedagogical purposes, like for you to learn about perturbation theory. What does your textbook say?

Comment: i thought it was a maser, but I think you are right, it is just an oscillatory potential, the maser comes later

Comment: I updated my answer with an example that might help

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The interpretation is quite clear if we think of Hamiltonian as the energy. If we apply the Hamiltonian $H_0$ to the state $|1>$ we get just the state $ E_1 |1>$. Similarly to the other state. In this sense the pertubation is just the interaction between the states $|1>$ and $|2>$.